# CS0234 - Cannot Instantiate C# class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made the same ASP.NET C# project in both VS2010 and MonoDevelop using these two classes among the standard files (*Site.Master*, *Web.Config*, *Default.aspx*, etc.) and recieve this same error (CS0234) seen at the bottom.

Login.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using mynamespace;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public partial class Logon 
    {
        public void btnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //ERROR IS HERE:
        mynamespace.Test session = new mynamespace.Test();

            //Obviously, this doesn't work either:
            Response.Write(session.echoUser());

        }
    }

}
```

Test.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using mynamespace;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string echoUser()
        {
            return "foobar";
        }
    }
}
```

I recieve the same error in both IDEs, here is the MonoDevelop error:

> The type or namespace 'Test' does not exist in the namespace 'mynamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) Logon.cs

Basically, the class Test refuses to instantiate. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a project reference between the two projects?

Comment: Right Click on the Test Project and click Add Reference, then in the Solution Tab you can select your other project.

Comment: These are two Class files, not two Projects. I just edited my OP to make more sense. I was trying to state that I tried this in a project in VS and a separate project in MonoDev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that Test class in an ASP.Net web project, then you need to place it in the App_Code folder, not just anywhere in the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer the projects to each other, if you haven't done so yet. I'm guessing that you don't get the intellisense to show the class in the other namespace, right?

You can see the *References* on the right side (most cases) under your project view. You can right click there and choose to *Add reference*. Then you browse to the binaries from the pther projects. (You might be able to point to the project itself too - I don't have VS in front of me at the moment.)

Also, It's a convention to use camel case for namespaces, so it should be *MyNameSpace*.

If the classes are in the same project, you might want to skip *using mynamespace* and refer to the class by *Test* intead of *mynamespace.Test*.

Comment: These are two Class files, not two Projects. I just edited my OP to make more sense. I was trying to state that I tried this in a project in VS and a separate project in MonoDev.

Comment: @Matthew2468 Are both classes in the same project? Then you shouldn't have the line *using mynamespace* at all. Also, you shouldn't need to specify *mynamespace.Test* but only *Test*.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project. I made the changes you mentioned and I get error CS0246

Comment: Do you get to see the class name using intellisense? See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If these are both in the same project, please check that both files are included in the project and have the "Build Action" property set to "Compile".  Please also check that all of these namespaces have exactly matching spelling and casing.